# Under what circumstances does bpf_get_socket_cookie() return 0

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, bpf, trafficshaping

[`bpf-helpers(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html) states that `bpf_get_socket_cookie()` returns 0 if the socket field is missing inside `skb`.

Under what conditions is the socket field missing in this context? Does it depend where in the datapath a BPF program is attached to? For instance, would `bpf_get_socket_cookie()` always return 0 in the case of a filter that attaches with `tc filter add dev ... ingress ... bpf ...` (on a Linux kernel 4.19, say)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The socket field is NULL if the packet wasn't demultiplexed to a socket yet. For TCP, that happens in [`tcp_v4_early_demux()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.6/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1725).

So yes, that will depend on where you attach your BPF program. You'd need to attach it before the packet is demultiplexed to a socket.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you also know whether the attachment point for `tc filter add dev ... ingress ... bpf ...` is one where the packet wasn't yet demultiplexed to a socket (in the case of TCP)? (I guess so, because traffic acts below L4.)

Comment: Or perhaps it depends: NULL at beginning of TCP flow, non-NULL for subsequent packages. Will try to dis/confirm by experiment.

Comment: FYI these experiments suggest that `bpf_get_socket_cookie()` does always return 0 for this kind of attachment, and that if one needs access to such cookies, a BPF program would have to be attached elsewhere in the datapath.